# Views field product link does not link to correct language

Tags: views, 8, commerce, i18n-l10n

It seems that, no matter how the view is configured, the product link field always links to the default language even if user is viewing the page in a different language. However, the product title field with link to product checkbox enabled goes to the correct language page.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong I can double-check?

Comment: What happens when you set the Views language setting for the relevant view to explicitly only show a non-default language?

Comment: i did try that and still goes to default language

Comment: Hmm, might be worth finding exact reproducible steps and then filing an issue in the Commerce issue queue.  As a workaround, you can probably use the rewrite rules in Views to get creative with the path to output the correct link.

Comment: since product link path itself is not correct i am not sure how i can can do anything creative with rewriting short of having two separate views which is something i really want to avoid. also, this may be a views issue and not commerce issue because an image also only offers link to content or file .. and not product. so not sure which module queue this would belong to.

Comment: so far only title works and there is no url formatter for it to use in a rewrite

Comment: Well, I don't know the details of your setup, but one way to avoid this kind of problem is to use the same path for multiple languages. For example, `/ja/about` for Japanese, `/es/about` for Spanish, and `/en/about` for English.  If you set up your URLs like this, it's easy to switch between languages (obviously you probably can't change the URLs easily on a live site).